# Connection refused for http requests intermittently on multiple certain networks but not others, OPNSense Firewall, maximum confusion

Tags: firewall, http, nat, connection-refused, opnsense

I have been using an OPNSense firewall at my business for about a year now and its worked great. We use it to host some websites, an email server, and wireguard for remote connections. All on a comcast business static ip block.

I noticed a while back on another office wifi network that I could not access the http services at all. I could ping the static ip (as well as the domain name, it is not a dns issue), connect to wireguard and receive my emails, but no http/s. When I turned off wifi and used my phones LTE, I could connect to the site just fine. But when wifi was re-enabled, no dice. I went back there another day, and everything worked fine.

This is now happening on my home network after installing a new router. Same ISP as before, just a new router with dd-wrt (I only added a few dhcp reservations and setup wifi). When I try to curl -v the website url, I get `connect to [ip address] port 80 failed: Connection refused`. When I got home from work today, it worked fine. An hour later, connection refused (LTE on phone worked). Now a while after that, it's all good again.

As far as I'm aware, my business site is the only site affected. I haven't been prevented from connecting to any others.

Connected via wireguard to the business network while the site was not working on my home net (once again, can connect to wireguard, ping etc. but no website), I could see activity in my nginx logs from remote servers and my phone on LTE, but no activity from my home network.

On the OPNSense firewall NAT I have 4 rules for http/s. http and https for our sites, and on another static ip http and https for mail server (i can send/receive emails as well when http is not functioning). I can confirm both web servers function correctly at all relevant times.

Can somebody please explain this madness to me? I have no idea what is going on with it.

Thanks

Comment: I would run `nping --trace --tcp -p 80 [ip address]` and that will send a series of SYN packets while incrementing the TTL, you've get back a load of `TTL=0 during transit` packets, but eventually you'll get back either a SYN-ACK for an accepted connection, or a RST-ACK for a refused connection. By comparing the refused and accepted traces, and assuming the packets took the same route both times, you'll know which device is responsible for the refused connection. It's anyone's guess why the connection is being refused, but knowing where the buck stops is a good start

Comment: @RobbieMckennie Thanks this is useful. I ran the command and got this output repeated: 
 `SENT (47.0853s) TCP 192.168.1.7:11293 > {remote_ip}:80 S ttl=48 id=23489 iplen=40  seq=984309662 win=1480 
RCVD (47.1074s) ICMP [{remote_ip} > 192.168.1.7 Port 80 unreachable (type=3/code=3) ] IP [ttl=60 id=4131 iplen=72 ]` 
So I am receiving packets back from the server, but it seems like its reacting as if the port is blocked.

Comment: I believe that if your issue is with a router between your machine and the target server, the return packet is still going to say it's from your remote IP, so it's important to get a trace while it's working and compare them